# Can't access Restful WebService in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I've created a restful web service using visual studio and c#. I can access the webservice itself, but not the the methods that return json data. Currently I have the 2 c# files in the AppCode(restservice.cs and Irestservice.svc.cs) folder and the webservice.svc file in the main directory of the website. They are all in one namespace.

When I type in example.com/RestfulWeb.svc , The service pops up
Put when I type in example.com/RestfulWeb.svc/convertOpenDT I get an error saying the resource has been removed or unavailable.

Here is the code in the interfaceClass

```
namespace RestServiceImpl {

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            //ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "convertOpenDT/")]
        String convertOpenDT();
    }

}
```

This is the service itself:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="RestServiceImpl.RestServiceImpl" CodeBehind="RestServiceImpl.svc.cs"  %>
```

Then this is the code behind for the service Which is in the AppCode folder with the first cs file

```
namespace RestServiceImpl
{
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)] 
public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
{ 
    #region IRestService Members
    SqlConnection dbConn;
   public RestServiceImpl()
    {
        dbConn = DBConnect.getConnection();

    } 


        public string convertOpenDT()
```

If anyone has any suggestion or if I'm miss placing files please let me know.

Comment: So I think the problem is it works with http: but not https:.

Comment: Hosting WCF with https is not so straightforward. You have to create certificate which is bound to specific address.